# Odd numbers to Even numbers

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-property

Remember the old puzzle?

*"Can you take just one letter out of an odd number and make it even?"*

Note the clever wording. It just says make it *even*; not "make it *an even number*"...

So here is my version:

> Find the **smallest** odd integers and remove "n" letters. The
> remaining letters must be an **even number**. The "n" is from 2 to 9. (I
> could not find a solution to just taking away 1 letter.) The integers
> must be less than 100. Once the letters are removed you cannot
> rearrange the remaining letters.

No partial answers please. Need 8 numbers.

If you can find a solution for n=1, please report that.

Comment: I see everyone has answered with positive integers. What's your definition of "smallest"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are

> 2 five to iv (roman numerals)
>  3 twenty-one to twenty
>  4 fifteen to ten
>  5 thirteen to ten
>  6 seventeen to ten
>  7 twenty-five to ten
>  8 twenty-three to ten
>  9 seventy-seven to ten

Thanks to @LukasRotter for reminding me it was odd to even

@Amoz and @Stiv suggested some rather clever ways for a solution to n=1

> iii to ii  (@amoz)
>  ONe to Ne (atomic number 10... even!) (@stiv)

Also, the solution to the "old joke" mentioned is

> seven to even

Comment: Base numbers have to be odd. So just +1 for your #3, #4 and #7

Comment: @LukasRotter oh doh, missed that requirement.  thanks!

Comment: If five to iv is legitimate, is iii to ii valid? (removing one)

Comment: @Amoz looks like you found a 1 removal!

Comment: How about removing one letter out of an odd number to make it an even *atomic* number: (O)Ne [#10]?!

Comment: @Stiv you have periodic table prowess today!  If you don't mind, I'll add yours and Amoz's cleverness to the answer

Comment: By all means, feel free. I've had an idea for an alternative answer, which I'll post separately, but by construction I will not be able to use the same method for a 1-er anyway! :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @SteveV's strategy, there is another way to approach this puzzle, by considering:

> numbers whose names can be reduced by **removing letters to leave the letter 'E' or the digraph 'EE'**, which are the [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) equivalents of the decimal values '14' and '238', respectively, i.e. even numbers! (There's nothing in the original question to preclude using base systems other than decimal, after all...)

Using this method, it is possible to use even smaller odd numbers than in that answer, right across the board:

> Removing 2 letters: ON**E** → E (14)
>  3: THR**EE** → EE (238)
>  4: THR**E**E → E (14)
>  5: **E**LEVEN → E (14)
>  6: THIRT**EE**N → EE (238)
>  7: THIRT**E**EN → E (14)
>  8: S**E**VENTEEN → E (14)
>  9: TWENTY THR**EE** → EE (238)
>
>  (NB There is no point considering the letters A, B, C or D, which are valued 10-13 in hexadecimal, since there are no English odd numbers less than 100 - a stipulation of the original puzzle - that contain these letters... You'll need to count as high as one-hun**d**red-**a**nd-one, one-**b**illion-and-one, or one-o**c**tillion-and-one before you find them! And while we *could* consider combinations involving the letter 'F' (15) also, the fact that it is rarer than the letter 'E' in the names of small odd numbers actually means there is always a smaller solution using 'E's alone...)

Note that it is impossible to use this same technique to find a solution requiring the removal of just *one* letter...

> Unless we 'up our game' even further and switch from using hexadecimal to using a higher base, like base-24! Then we can legally do:
>
>  Removing 1 letter: O**NE** → NE (566 in base-24)